# Django cursor pagination

Tags: django

I'm looking for a solution to get a cursor pagination in Django.

To be clear, cursor pagination is (I think) a system of pagination like Facebook. You just have to scroll down to load more contents.

Comment: I think what you're talking about is known as 'lazy loading' (sometimes endless pagination).

Comment: Yeah may be. So I have to search with this name.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [these packages](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=django+pagination&submit=search). Not having used it, but [django-el-pagination](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-el-pagination/3.1.0) looks a likely fit.

Comment: I tried it, but I have an error, so I'm searching another.